# XPath, getting value of min attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-2.0

SO I've never used XSLT before, and i've only used XPath in it's simplest form.
I have a Xml element "Earth" with two attributes Stamina and willpower. Both contain numbers. 
What I'm trying to do is Display next to the word "Earth" the value of the least of these attributes.
I can't seem to workout how to call functions in XPath.

Here is my XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  version="2.0">
  <!--<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"> 
    -->

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Rings"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//Rings">
    <h2>Rings</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Earth</th>
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="fn:min(fn:number(Earth/@*))"/>
        </th>
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: All the examples for XLST i find on W3eC are too trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Visual Studio comes pre-packaged with the .NET XSLT processor XslCompiledTransform, and this is an XSLT 1.0 processor.

On the other side, `min()` is a standard function in XPath 2.0 and not in XPath 1.0. XSLT 1.0 uses only XPath 1.0.

**An XSLT 1.0 solution to the problem**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Earth">
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "@*[not(. > ../@*)][1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (as you haven't provided one!):

```
<Rings>
 <Earth stamina="3" willpower="6"/>
</Rings>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
3
```

In .NET it is possible to use a third party XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon.NET or XQSharp. Below is an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="Earth">
     <xsl:sequence select="min(@*)[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I think with this example is should be able to work out everthing I need to know about XSLT.

Comment: @Oxinabox: You are welcome. I hope you need to know about XSLT even more :)

Answer (score 2):

Note also that `min(number(@*))` is incorrect in XPath 2.0 - you can't apply the number() function to a sequence of nodes to get a sequence of numbers. It should be `min(@*/number())`. However, it the input is unvalidated, all attributes will be untypedAtomic, and the min() function will convert untypedAtomic values to numbers automatically. However, if there are attributes that are not numeric, then the automatic conversion will cause an error, while use of number() will generate a NaN value, which will cause the result of min() also to be NaN. If you want the minimum value of all those attributes that are numeric, try `min(@*[. castable as xs:double])`.

Answer (score 0):

The `min()` function is only available in XSLT 2.0. You should try using a 2.0 processor ([Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: I'm using MS Visual studio 2010. (and I assume that support it?)
 I was aware min() is XSLT 2.0 (note the question was tagged with, Xpath 2.0)
I thought I was using functions/namespaces wrong

Comment: Microsoft's XSLT processors like MSXML 3 and MSXML 6 in the COM world as well as XslCompiledTransform in the .NET world are XSLT 1.0 processors. There are however third party XSLT 2.0 implementations, namely AltovaXML in the COM world and Saxon 9 and XQSharp in the .NET world. Thus if you want to use XPath 2.0 functions within XSLT then you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor. Note that you can then use those functions without using a prefix.

Comment: Apparently, it is only XLST 1 with visual studio... (EDIT: Oh i missed Martins post)